# Possibilites of adding up values to a set value / Reverse Bin Packing

Tags: vb.net

Context: Mass Spec analysis, trying to work out all possible combinations of atoms to make up an ion of given mass `massDecomposing`. All the `dVCountX` parameters are passed in as 0, and `valueToDecomp` is passed in as a `New Integer()`. `decomposedOutputCounter` is a variable.

```
Sub decomposeValue(ByVal massDecomposing As Integer, ByVal dVNestingCounter As Integer, ByVal dVCountC As Integer, ByVal dVCountH As Integer, ByVal dVCountN As Integer, _
                   ByVal dVCountO As Integer, ByVal dVCountF As Integer, ByVal dVCountBr79 As Integer, ByVal dVCountBr81 As Integer, ByVal dVCountCl As Integer, _
                   ByVal dVCountI As Integer, ByVal ParamArray valueToDecomp() As Integer)
    If dVNestingCounter = 0 Then
        valueToDecomp(0) = massDecomposing
    End If


    If valueToDecomp(dVNestingCounter) = 0 Then
        'lengthy code that puts the values of dVCountX into an array, I know this works
        'decomposedOutputCounter is used to ensure each possibility has its own postion in the array
        decomposedOutputCounter = decomposedOutputCounter + 1



    End If


    For Each x In atomicMassArray
        If x <> 0 Then

            If valueToDecomp(dVNestingCounter) - x >= 0 Then

                Select Case x
                    Case 1
                        dVCountH += 1
                    Case 12
                        dVCountC += 1
                    Case 13
                        dVCountN += 1
                    Case 16
                        dVCountO += 1
                    Case 19
                        dVCountF += 1
                    Case 35
                        dVCountCl += 1    
                    Case 79
                        dVCountBr79 += 1
                    Case 81
                        dVCountBr81 += 1
                    Case 129
                        dVCountI += 1
                End Select
                ReDim Preserve valueToDecomp(dVNestingCounter + 1)
                valueToDecomp(dVNestingCounter + 1) = valueToDecomp(dVNestingCounter) - x
                decomposeValue(massDecomposing, dVNestingCounter + 1, dVCountC, dVCountH, dVCountN, dVCountO, dVCountF, dVCountBr79, dVCountBr81, dVCountCl, dVCountI, valueToDecomp)
            End If

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Now, I'm reasonably sure that the code above goes through and considers all possibilities, but when the values of the `dVCountX` variables are outputted, they're wrong, *I think* due to each time `valueToDecomp(dVNestingCounter)` should reach 0, it for some reason goes through extra recursion a number of times equal to `decomposedOutputCounter`

From my googling, I think this could be considered a version of the Subset Sum problem, except trying to find all the possibilities when your set has an infinite amount of each value (1, 12, 13 etc)

Comment: This is a very complicated question.  There is a lot of Mass Spec stuff that really doesn't apply to the question.  If you can slim this down to the minimum code that reproduces the issue we can help better, or you may see the problem yourself.  I am wondering, though, why there is an `End If` under `Case 35`.  I can't imagine that compiled.

Comment: @GlennHolden the `End If` is a remnant of trimming out some `Console.WriteLine`s

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED (by a colleague IRL):
Going back to an older version, where `valueToDecomp` is just an integer parameter (so `dVNestingCounter` is unneeded), and from there each of the `CountX += 1` lines to a call of `decomposeValue` with `CountX+1` as a parameter (replacing X as appropriate). Also, remove the existing call of `decomposeValue`.